# Living in a horse lorry

Tags: uk

What are some of the main reasons horse lorries are so cheap to buy? *(they just seem very cheap and it instantly makes me suspicious)*

Such lorries can be converted into a housetruck and be lived in, which may be an attractively economical way of building a housetruck, and a low environmental impact form of housing.

[image]

Comment: You consider to live in a horse lorry?  Are you a horse?  I'm confused.  Can you add a picture of what you are referring to?

Comment: [These](https://www.google.nl/search?q=horse+lorry&source=lnms&tbm=isch) are *horse lorries*: transportation trucks/vans for horses. You obviously meant something else.

Comment: horse box / horse lorry

Comment: I'm asking because horse lorries can be easily converted (http://www.housetruck.co.uk)

Comment: Among folks who live in converted trucks, horse trucks are popular (at least I was told so a while back) because when you have horses in the back you tend to drive defensively - good for brakes etc. They may be cheap because you can't do much with them besides transporting horses. That said, this question appears to be about alternative living which overlaps but is not the same as sustainable living.

Comment: @mart: your right. This question is more about alternative living then sustainable living. I hope this is the right place to post the question.

Comment: Personally I think that asking if living in a horse lorry reduces your environmental footprint is on-topic here, but asking why they are so cheap is not. I'm not sure but the latter may be covered by [Personal finance SE](http://money.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Can I move the question or do I have to re-ask it under `personal finance`?

Comment: @Sevenearths I've asked a moderator at Personal Finance if it's on-topic there. Awaiting a reply.

Comment: @Sevenearths Unfortunately the Personal Finance moderator thinks your question "would likely be closed as 'opinion'." I'm afraid you'll have to do some major editing or post a different related question.

Comment: cool. Thanks for your help. I think I'll leave it as is. `Off Topic` *(sounds about right)* and inquire somewhere else

Comment: @THelper what about [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @LShaver from my (limited) experience with that site I've gathered that questions there have to be about manufacturing, maintaining or repairing vehicles.

Comment: I found out part of the reason. You have to get a category C1 license (<7.5 tonne) or a category C license (over 7.5 tonne) and these can cost between £800-£1200 all in. + there is only a small percentage of the population that wants to (and can afford to) move their horse round the country.